# avatarURL in an embed (.setThumbnail)

Tags: discord.js

I would like an avatar URL of the person I tagged.

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I don't get an error. Code:

```
var user = message.mentions.members.first();

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("test")
    .setDescription("test")
    .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL)
    .setTimestamp();


    message.channel.send(embed);

}
```

I hope someone can help me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
`user.displayAvatarURL()`
Hope this helps!

Comment: Now i get this error `(node:11132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: user.displayAvatarURL is not a function`

Comment: ```
var user = message.mentions.members.first();

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("test")
    .setDescription("test")
    .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL())
    .setTimestamp();


    message.channel.send(embed);
```

Is that what your code looks like now?

Comment: Yes, this is how it looks now

Comment: Did you have another variable called `user` as well before this? Also, do you mind putting all your code for this command into a pastebin? It would be a lot easier, thanks!

Comment: No, I have not used user more often. https://pastebin.com/9WCMKitq

Comment: Alright, everything looks normal. What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: Version v12.2.0

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe try changing the variable's name to 'User' instead of 'user'? Hope it works

Comment: Try removing the .setThumbnail() line and running it. What happens?

Comment: Yes, that is of no use to me, I want it in my embed

Comment: I know, but remove it just for now and run the command. Does it send the embed?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this example on the official documentation:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/avatars

So maybe do:

```js
message.author.displayAvatarURL()
```